# Web Form Cutting Off After Special Character

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a simple web form where a person can enter into a textbox what kind of project they want. For example, they may type in: Sales & Projection report needs to be fixed.
They then click a submit button and it gets sent off to a third party website that keeps track of our projects.
The problem is, in the example given above, everything gets cut off after the '&' symbol.
it gets sent like this:

```
String request = "fct=createorcopyproject&guid=" + guid + "&projectname=" + TxtProjectName.Text + "&projectdesc=" + TxtDescription.Text +
        "&nexttasknumber=1&budgethours=0&budgetcost=0&estimatedstartdate=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "&estimatedenddate=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "&estimatedhours=0&estimatedexpenses=0&projectpriorityid=" + priorityIndex + "&projectstatusid=NULL&projecttemplate=0&contactname=" + user +
        "&defaultestimatedtime=0&defaulttaskstartdate=1&defaulttaskenddate=1&defaulttaskactualdates=2&clientid=" + areaIndex + "&createdefaults=True&languagedefaults=EN&projecttemplateid=0000003&keeptemplatelink=false&copyprojectassignments=True&copyprojectdocuments=True&copyforumtopics=False&copytasks=False&adjusttaskdates=False&copytaskdocuments=False&copytaskassignments=False&markproject=False&format=ds";
```

Where TxtDescription.Text is where we are getting the cutoff.
Is this something on their end or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) method to encode the values you send in an URL (assuming this is an URL)